# Standard deviation in batches

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, pytorch

I am using this [function](http://pytorch.org/docs/torch.html#torch.std) to compute the standard deviation of my output. I am evaluating my model on 2000 examples, in batches of 4. Can I just take the standard deviation per batch and then divide by 2000 ?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what you've done so far?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. Have a look at [this post](http://notmatthancock.github.io/2017/03/23/simple-batch-stat-updates.html) where batch updates of the mean and the standard deviation are explained in a nice way, with both math and code.